# GROUP BY по части поля. Возможно ли?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + title           + num +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1 + name slim       +   5 +
+  2 + name frog       +   6 +
+  3 + name frog       +   2 +
+  4 + nick one        +   8 +
+  5 + nick two        +   3 +
+  6 + nick strong man +   7 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Хочу командой GROUP BY сделать группировку, по полю title, но по значению ДО первого пробела

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE 1
GROUP BY команда_которую_не_знаю(`title`)
ORDER BY `num` ASC
```

На выходе охота получить что то типа

```
++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + title + num +
++++++++++++++++++++
+  3 + name  +   2 +
+  5 + nick  +   3 +
++++++++++++++++++++
```

Такое возможно? Если да, подскажите как написать запрос

p.s. в данный момент делаю запрос ко всей таблице, и уже после запроса обрабатываю данные

---

благодаря мудрым советам @Akina - можно сделать запрос

```
SELECT `id`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`title`, ' ', 1), `num`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE 1
GROUP BY `title`
ORDER BY `num` ASC
```

но команда GROUP BY перестает работать

```
++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + title + num +
++++++++++++++++++++
+  3 + name  +   2 +
+  1 + name  +   5 +
+  2 + name  +   6 +
+  5 + nick  +   3 +
+  6 + nick  +   7 +
+  4 + nick  +   8 +
++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: *команда_которую_не_знаю* `GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1)`. И соответственно то же выражение в выходном наборе. *На выходе охота получить что то типа* Вот именно что "типа". Мало того, что фиг знает, от какой именно записи будут взяты значения полей `id` и `num`, так ещё и не гарантируется (хотя и маловероятно), что они будут из одной и той же записи. PS. А нафига тебе `id`? PPS. Версия сервера - не восьмая случайно?

Comment: если обрезать поле title до первого пробела то после указанного ORDER BY - id и num mysql ищет сам

Comment: [Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) считает иначе. *In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic* И ей я верю больше, чем чьим-то необоснованным утверждениям. А намёк на недетерминированность результата я лично считаю веским основанием для изменения подхода к решению задачи...

Comment: И уточните всё же версию сервера. И да, это в данном случае важно.

Comment: *но команда GROUP BY перестает работать* Ну ещё бы... выражение группировки в показанном запросе немного отличается от того, что я предложил... Кстати, обратите внимание на записи 2 и 3. В показанном запросе они обязаны были "схлопнуться" - следовательно, визуально одинаковое значение поля title на самом деле в них различается.

Comment: MySQL 5.7. Немного дописал вопрос

Comment: 5.7 - это грустно, оконные функции недоступны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, для чего в выходном наборе поле `id`. И тем более непонятно, что должно выводиться, если одному и тому же (судя по ORDER BY - минимальному) значению `num` соответствует несколько разных `id`...

Додумывая задачу, считаю, что наиболее верным будет следующий запрос:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`title`, ' ', 1) title, min(`num`) num
FROM `my_table`
-- WHERE 1
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`title`, ' ', 1)
ORDER BY `num` ASC
```

Если всё же `id` необходим, то запрос будет таким:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.id) id, t2.title, t2.num
FROM my_table t1
JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`title`, ' ', 1) title, min(`num`) num
      FROM `my_table`
      GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`title`, ' ', 1)) t2
   ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.title, ' ', 1) = t2.title
  AND t1.num = t2.num
GROUP BY t2.title, t2.num
ORDER BY num
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee4f8d68ebd03553421d2f491adebed4)

Comment: Оно! Этот приятный момент, когда узнаешь много нового )